# ATmega8 basic math operation understanding

Tags: math, avr, atmega

1. Can somebody tell me how ATmega8 (or similar 8-bit proc.) implements math operation like subtraction, addition, division, multiplication on register logic?
2. Where can I read about speed of this operation? (I know that division and floating point operations are slow BUT how much time (how many microseconds)does it take?

Comment: Read the datasheet for the processor you want to learn about.  All instruction timings are in the datasheets.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and more about microelectronic fundamentals than anything specific.

Comment: There is no "AVR timing on floating point" - The AVR range doesn't have any floating point support in hardware, so needs to rely on software implementations. And those differ in their performance, which might even be a non-constant value depending on arguments. Floating point number crunching isn't exactly the main domain of an AVR MCU, so FP is very rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

The [website](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_instruction_list.html) or in the [manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf) include the number of cycles for each assembly instruction. But these only operate on bytes and do integer arithmetic.

The actual math instructions for the various C types are encoded in AVR Libc as assembly instructions, which you can download and examine. When the avr-gcc compiler comes across some operation, whether integer or floating point, the compiler inserts these functions instead. You will need to add up the cycles for all the machine instructions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves well **ATMega8** does not have **FPU** so all the floating operations are coded on 8 or 16 bit integers so even a simple operations will take some number of instructions instead of single one. For example addition `a+b`:

1. **extract exponent and mantissa of `a,b`**

   this involves few copy and shift/mask operations
2. **shift one mantissa to common exponent**

   few shift mask operations
3. **add mantissas**

   one `add`  and few times `adc`
4. **correct exponent of result**

   branch and few shift/mask operations
5. **encode result**

   this involves few copy and shift/mask operations

As you can see you got quite a few instructions for simple addition. The bigger bit-width of floating value the more instructions you need. So floats are many times slower ...

Now imagine things like `sin,cos,sqrt,...` which all involves approximation on some n-degree polynomial or binary search etc some of which are done on floating point values the speed goes down much much more.